# How do install utorrent on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, installation, bittorrent, utorrent, debian-stretch

I already try to install the utorrent follow the step of this [website](http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/utorrent-no-linux-manualmente/) , but the "utserve" don't work, just appear this message...[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDx7k.png)

Now I don't know if happen this because I installed it wrong or because there isn't uTorrent to Debian 9 (stretch).

Obs: When I installed the uTorrent only had to Debian 7 and Ubuntu, so I installed the uTorrent to Debian 7 64 bits

> If the text had some errors, sorry because I'm not fluent in English and it's first post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only utorrent server is supported on Linux although technically the client is supported through Wine. The latest version of Debian that the server officially supports is Debian 7 plus its trying to use a version of SSL thats vulnerable. There is no backport applications have to upgrade to at least libssl1.0.2.

So your options are limited the overall answer is just no. You'll have to wait for utorrent to update. However you could checkout Transmission Bittorrent as an alternative.

You should be able to get it to work if you were to backport libssl1.0.0 yourself but thats a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you sir, I didn't know the Transmission. I didn't thought in possibly of there are another options besides, uTorrent and Bit Torrent, really thanks.